# Last 2 digits of $\displaystyle 2014^{2001}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the last 2 digits of $2014^{2001}$? What about the last 2 digits of $9^{(9^{16})}$?

Comment: For $2014^{2001}$ the answer is 64. For $9^{9^{16}}$ I got 09.

Answer (score 4):

Finding the last two digits it equivalent to finding

$2014^{2001}\pmod{100}$.

Note $2014\equiv 14\pmod{100}$

Finding this requires using $100=25\times 4$ (coprime factors)

Is there a common solution to the system below?

$x\equiv 2014^{2001}\pmod{25}\equiv 14^{2001}\pmod{25}$

$x\equiv 2014^{2001}\pmod{4}\equiv 2^{2001}\pmod{4}$

Comment: It might be added that [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) makes the computation of $14^{2001}$ mod 25 extremely simple, since $\phi(25)=20$. It can be done in one's head (as can the subsequent application of the CRT).

Comment: How to find $x\equiv 2^{2001}\pmod{4}$

Comment: What is $2^3\pmod 4$? What is $2^4\pmod 4$?

Comment: x=4n for any integer n

Comment: Yes! The solution is a multiple of 4 which satisfies the $\pmod{25}$ equation too!

Comment: Ok so if $x=4n$ is the solution to the first equation, then $4n\equiv 14^{2001}\equiv 14\pmod{25}$. **Hint:** $4\cdot 19=1\pmod{25}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For finding last two digits you need to reduce this modulo $100$. That is you ne need to find
$$2014^{2001} \equiv ? \pmod{100}.$$
This is the  same as asking
$$14^{2001} \equiv ? \pmod{100}.$$

Now in order to facilitate computation, you need to use [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). But keep in mind that $\gcd(14,100) = 2.$ So you need to adjust things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's Theorem

$2014^{\phi(25)}=2014^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{25}\implies2014^{2000}\equiv 1\pmod{25}\implies2014^{2001}\equiv 2014\pmod{25}\implies2014^{2001}\equiv 14\pmod{25}$

Obviously $2014^{2001}\equiv 0\pmod{4}$

Let $2014^{2001}=25n+14\implies25n+14\equiv 0\pmod{4}\implies n\equiv 2\pmod{4}$

$2014^{2001}=25n+14=25(4k+2)+14=64+100k$

Answer (score 0):

$9^{\phi(100)}=9^{40}\equiv 1\pmod{100}\implies9^{40k}\equiv 1\pmod{100}$

Now consider $9^{16}=40k+?$ , that is the same as finding $x\equiv 9^{16}\pmod{40}$

$9^{\phi(40)}=9^{16}\equiv 1\pmod{40}\implies 9^{16}=40k+1$

$9^{40k}\equiv 1\pmod{100}\implies 9^{40k+1}\equiv 9\pmod{100}$